# Writing compressed files using nc_create

Tags: c, netcdf

I am using the netcdf library from UCAR to create a netCDF file. The command to create a netCDF file is here:
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-c/nc_005fcreate.html

If I use the flags NC_NETCDF4 | NC_CLASSIC_MODEL in nc_create, will it create a compressed netCDF file?

Comment: What did it output? The word "compress" does not appear in your link, and the values documented for `int cmode` argument don't suggest it either.

Comment: In NetCDF4 compression is set on the variable level. Read https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-c/nc_005fdef_005fvar_005fdeflate.html#nc_005fdef_005fvar_005fdeflate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compression is set in the variables rather than the file using the `nc_def_var_deflate` function. I used the example from the Unidata website (and removed the error checks to make it readable here, mea culpa). What you can do is play with the `deflate_level` parameter to see the difference in file size. Do not expect miracles, my experience is that you mostly gain in the order of 10 to 20 percent.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <netcdf.h>

#define NDIMS 1
#define NX 102400

int main()
{
    int ncid, x_dimid, varid;
    double* data_out = new double[NX];

    for (int x=0; x<NX; ++x)
        data_out[x] = (double)(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX;

    nc_create("test.nc", NC_CLOBBER | NC_NETCDF4, &ncid);

    nc_def_dim(ncid, "x", NX, &x_dimid);

    nc_def_var(ncid, "data", NC_DOUBLE, NDIMS, &x_dimid, &varid);
    int shuffle = 1;
    int deflate = 1;        // This switches compression on (1) or off (0).
    int deflate_level = 8;  // This is the compression level in range 1 (less) - 9 (more).
    nc_def_var_deflate(ncid, varid, shuffle, deflate, deflate_level);
    nc_enddef(ncid);

    nc_put_var_double(ncid, varid, data_out);
    nc_close(ncid);

    delete[] data_out;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Chiel, this helps. Do I need to modify code to read in a netCDF file that has been compressed?

Comment: No, the library takes care of it. See the FAQ: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/faq.html#fv9

Comment: Compared to classic model files, compressed files in my particular case have been of the order of 25% of the original, so it can be significant. You can check possible compression levels with nccopy command, something like:
nccopy -4 -d 9 -s -u infile.nc outfile.nc